# Copying CImage leads to runtime error

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, visual-studio-2015

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlimage.h>
using namespace std;
void locate(CImage img, int i, int j)
{
    img.GetPixelAddress(i, j);
};
int main()
{
    CImage img;
    img.Load(_T("./1.png"));
    locate(img, 0, 0);
    //img.GetPixelAddress(0, 0);
    unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *)(img.GetPixelAddress(0, 0));
    cout <<*p << endl;//give me a runtime error
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me a runtime error.I'm using vs2015 on windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlimage.h>
using namespace std;
void locate(CImage img, int i, int j)
{
    img.GetPixelAddress(i, j);
};
int main()
{
    CImage img;
    img.Load(_T("./1.png"));
    //locate(img, 0, 0);
    img.GetPixelAddress(0, 0);
    unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *)(img.GetPixelAddress(0, 0));
    cout <<*p << endl;//works fine
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles ,but it looks basiclly the same as the code above .
I just replace the locate function part with the codes that actually executes .  Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: You are not checking if the image was loaded.

Comment: There's nothing in your question that suggests a potential compiler bug. I have a sneaky feeling that `CImage` does not like being copied by value. Trying declaring the first parameter to `locate()` as "CImage &img".

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time a noob blamed issues they were having on compiler bugs I could retire.

Comment: If the problem does turn out to be that CImage has broken copy semantics, you could call that a VS bug

Comment: Also you should give exact details of the error, not just "a runtime error"

Comment: MFC CImage does seem to have user-provided destructor, and not user-defined copy-constructor; doesn't bode well. It's possible HDC and HBITMAP members are internally reference counted I guess

Answer (score 0):

This is the prototype for [CImage::GetPixelAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w01eyy56.aspx)

```
void* GetPixelAddress(int x, int y);
```

It returns a pointer. If you cast it to character array, `cout` will try to print a string. So just print it as is:

```
cout << img.GetPixelAddress(0, 0) << endl;
//or
void* p = img.GetPixelAddress(0, 0);
cout << p << endl;
//or
printf("%p\n", p);
```

or you can cast to `INT_PTR`:

```
INT_PTR p = (INT_PTR)img.GetPixelAddress(0, 0);
cout << std::hex << p << endl;
```